# Create column from non null values in other column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column with some ints and some null values in a pandas dataframe. How do I replace the ints with the float values from another column (by same row), but leave all the nulls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need exact columns and df to be sure, but can you try this:

```
df.loc[df['ints'].notnull(),'ints'] = df['floats']
```

where df is your dataframe, ints is the integer column and floats is the float column.